# How can I click each list of drop-down menu using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I tried to collect every relative data in the drop-down menus in the first row of this page.(http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) The manufacturers I would like to select is ['아우디', 'BMW', '벤츠'] and models and detail-models are like below in code. What I would like to do is click the first drop-down menu and click items in the second drop-down menu defined in its list and then the third drop-down menu.

Below is the result that I would like to have:

```
BMW
====clicked maker
5시리즈
====clicked model
5시리즈 (03~10년)
====clicked detail model
뉴 5시리즈 (10년~현재)
====clicked detail model

X 시리즈
====clicked model
X6 (08년~현재)
====clicked detail model
뉴 X5 (14년~현재)
====clicked detail model
뉴 X3 (11년~현재)
====clicked detail model
....
벤츠
====clicked maker
S 클래스
====clicked model
S클래스 (06년~13년)
====clicked detail model
S클래스 (54~06년)
====clicked detail model
뉴 S클래스 (14년~현재)
====clicked detail model
...
```

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import quote
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import re
import time
from time import sleep
from urllib import parse
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

url = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(url)

res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = res.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

preset_models_audi = ['A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'Q3', 'Q5', 'Q7', 'TT', 'S', 'SQ', 'RS', 'R8']
preset_models_bmw = ['1시리즈', '2시리즈', '3시리즈', '4시리즈', '5시리즈', '6시리즈', '7시리즈', 'GT', 'X시리즈', 'M시리즈', 'Z시리즈', 'i3',
                'i8']
preset_models_benz = ['A클래스', 'B클래스', 'C클래스', 'E클래스', 'S클래스', 'M클래스', 'GLE클래스', 'GLS클래스', 'GLC클래스', 'GLA클래스',
                 'GLK클래스',
                 'G클래스', 'SLK', 'SL', 'SLC클래스', 'CL클래스', 'CLS클래스', 'CLA클래스', 'SLS', 'AMG GT', 'CLK',
                 '마이바흐']

makers = ['아우디', 'BMW', '벤츠']

preset_detail_models_audi = ["A1 (10년~현재)", "뉴 A3 (14년~현재)", "A3 (96~13년)", "뉴 A4 (16년~현재)", "A4 (09~16년)",
                        "A4 (94~09년)",
                        "뉴 A5 (11년~현재)", "A5 (07~11년)", "뉴 A6 (11년~현재)", "A6 (09~11년)", "A6 (94~09년)",
                        "A7 (10년~현재)",
                        "뉴 A8 (10년~현재)", "A8 (94~10년)", "Q3 (11년~현재)", "Q5 (08년~현재)", "뉴 Q7 (16년~현재)",
                        "Q7 (05~15년)",
                        "뉴 TTS (15년~현재)", "뉴 TT (15년~현재)", "TTS (06~14년)", "TT (06~14년)", "TT (98~06년)",
                        "S모델",
                        "SQ5 (13년~현재)", "RS3 (11년~현재)", "RS4 (00년~현재)", "RS5 (10년~현재)", "RS6 (02~10년)",
                        "RS7 (14년~현재)",
                        "R8 (06년~현재)"]
preset_detail_models_bmw = ["뉴 1시리즈 (13년~현재)", "1시리즈 (04~12년)", "2시리즈 (14년~현재)",
                       "뉴 3시리즈 (12년~현재)", "3시리즈 (05~13년)", "4시리즈 (14년~현재)",
                       "뉴 5시리즈 (10년~현재)", "5시리즈 (03~10년)",
                       "뉴 6시리즈 (12년~현재)", "6시리즈 (76~11년)",
                       "뉴 7시리즈 (16년~현재)", "7시리즈 (09~15년)", "7시리즈 (77~09년)",
                       "그란투리스모 (10년~현재)",
                       "뉴 X1 (16년~현재)", "X1 (09~15년)", "뉴 X3 (11년~현재)", "X3 (04~11년)",
                        "X4 (14년~현재)", "X5 (99~13년)", "뉴 X5 (14년~현재)", "X6 (08년~현재)", "뉴 X6 (15년~현재)",
                       "M시리즈 (72년~현재)", "뉴 Z4 (09년~현재)", "Z4 (02~09년)", "i3 (14년~현재)",
                       "i8 (15년~현재)"]
preset_detail_models_benz = ["뉴 A클래스 (13년~현재)", "A클래스 (97~12년)", "뉴 B클래스 (12년~현재)", "B클래스 (05년~현재)",
                        "뉴 C클래스 (15년~현재)", "C클래스 (08년~14년)", "뉴 E클래스 (16년~현재)", "E클래스 (09~16년)",
                        "뉴 S클래스 (14년~현재)", "S클래스 (06년~13년)", "뉴 M클래스 (12~15년)", "M클래스 (97~12년)",
                        "GLE클래스 (16년~현재)", "GLS클래스 (16년~현재)", "GLC클래스 (16년~현재)", "GLA클래스 (14년~현재)",
                        "GLK클래스 (09~15년)", "G클래스 (79년~현재)", "뉴 SLK클래스 (12~16년)", "SLK클래스 (04~11년)",
                        "뉴 SL클래스 (12년~현재)", "SL클래스 (54~11년)", "SLC클래스 (16년~현재)",
                        "뉴 CL클래스 (07~13년)", "CL클래스 (92~07년)",
                        "뉴 CLS클래스 (10년~현재)", "CLS클래스 (04~10년)", "CLA클래스 (14년~현재)",
                             "SLS AMG (10~14년)",
                             "AMG GT (14년~현재)", "CLK클래스 (96~09년)", "마이바흐 (02년~현재)]"]

makers_found = [
    ('%s' % o.get_attribute('text'), '%s' % parse.unquote(o.get_attribute('href')))
    for o
    in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_maker ul.list li a")
    if o.get_attribute('text') != '전체'
    ]

for maker_found in makers_found:
    if maker_found[0] in makers:
        ma = maker_found[0]
        if maker_found[0] == '아우디':
            driver.execute_script(maker_found[1])
            preset_models = preset_models_audi
            preset_detail_models = preset_detail_models_audi
        elif maker_found[0] == 'BMW':
            driver.execute_script(maker_found[1])
            preset_models = preset_models_bmw
            preset_detail_models = preset_detail_models_bmw
        elif maker_found[0] == '벤츠':
            driver.execute_script(maker_found[1])
            preset_models = preset_models_benz
            preset_detail_models = preset_detail_models_benz

        print(maker_found[0])
        print("====clicked maker")
        time.sleep(1)

        models = [
            ('%s' % o.get_attribute('text'), '%s' % parse.unquote(o.get_attribute('href')))
            for o
            in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_group ul.list li a")
            if o.text != '전체'
            ]

        for model in models:
            if model[0] in preset_models:
                driver.execute_script(model[1])
                mo = model[0]
                print(model[0])
                sleep(.75)
                print('====clicked model')

                detail_models = [
                    ('%s' % o.get_attribute('text'), '%s' % parse.unquote(o.get_attribute('href')))
                    for o
                    in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_model ul.list li a")
                    if o.get_attribute('text') != '전체']

                for detail_model in detail_models:

                    print(detail_model[0])

                    if detail_model[0] in preset_detail_models:
                        driver.execute_script(detail_model[1])
                        de = detail_model[0]
                        print(detail_model[0])
                        sleep(.75)
                        print('====clicked detail model')
```

Please help me to work this out.